# undefined variable Posts

Tags: laravel

I am trying to complete a search filter feature for my website however i am recieving the following error:

Undefined variable: posts (View:

```
@foreach($posts as $distance)

 <option value="{{$distance->distance}}">{{ $distance->distance}}</option>

 @endforeach
```

Here is my search.blade.php (error occuring:

```
   @foreach($posts as $distance)
 <option value="{{$distance->distance}}">{{ $distance->distance}}</option>
 @endforeach
</select>
```

SearchController.php

```
    function index()
{
 $posts = DB::table('posts')
     ->groupBy('title')
     ->get();
 return view('posts.search')->with('posts', $posts);
}
```

Does anyone know why i am receiving the error even thoough my posts have been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your Controller**

```
public function index()
{
 $posts = DB::table('posts')
     ->groupBy('title')
     ->get();
 return view('posts.search',compact('posts'));
}
```

**In your model**

```
 @foreach($posts as $distance)

 <option value="{{$distance->id}}">{{ $distance->distance}}</option>

 @endforeach
```

Comment: It clearly states in the documentation that with() should work, so instead of getting him to look at something else, we should find out why it is not working.Documentation for reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/views

Comment: `post::with('distance')->get();` like